# Image path not referred the root folder while include the file in another file

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a file structure like this.

```
|-- header.html
|-- app
    |-- details.html
|-- img
    |-- image.jpg
```

After I included the image in `header.html`

```
<img src="img/image.jpg" />
```

Its working fine now.

When I include the `header.html` file within `details.html` file the **image** path is not correctly pointing the image folder.

In AngularJS I included,

In `details.html`

```
<div data-ng-include=" '../header.html' " >
</div>
```

Can anyone tell what the mistake is here?.

Comment: need sample code to understand what you applied and what result you are expecting

Comment: *when I include the header.html file with in details.html file the image path not correctly pointing the image folder.* How are you including it? Can you post the code please?

Comment: when you include an html page into another, the code only gets included so if you want to point to the image you have to provide the full path or in this example particularly you can say `<img src="../img/image.jpg" />`

Answer (score 1):

details.html is looking at the path:

```
app/img/image.jpg.
```

since app is details' parent folder.

Use the absolute path (http://www.yoursite.com/img/image.jpg)
or take a step back with ".."
so in details.html:

```
<img src="../img/image.jpg"/>
```

Comment: No, please check my question. I included the header.html file with in the details.html file
not the image alone.

Comment: I think you added more to your question since I answered it :)
I believe the context of the external html object is still the same. Doesn't it work if you replace it "../img/image.jpg" in details?